# Highlight current day in PHP calendar

Tags: php, html, calendar

I am using the calendar code from this site:

http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-web-calendar-in-php

How do you highlight the current day?

I was trying to add additional variable in

```
private function _showDay($cellNumber){
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
```

and then

```
if($this->currentDate == '{$today}') { //DO SOMETHING }
```

I was thinking of creating a new CSS class with a border or using different background color. But it may duplicate with already defined classes such as 'start' or 'end'.

Any ideas how to go about this? I would like to keep it simple and do not use JavaScript if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Found it in the comment section of the webpage.

Condensed version:

create a new style element

```
div#calendar ul.dates li.this_today { background-color: black; color: white; }
```

find the method

```
private function _showDay($cellNumber){
```

and add this:

```
$today_day = date("d");
$today_mon = date("m");
$today_yea = date("Y");

$class_day = ($cellContent == $today_day && $this->currentMonth == $today_mon && $this->currentYear == $today_yea ? "this_today" : "nums_days");
return '<li class="' . $class_day . '">' . $cellContent . '</li>' . "\r\n";
```